# Plotting multiple subplots with pandas visualization tools

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using IGN review dataset from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/egrinstein/20-years-of-games), and i'm trying to get a frequency plot by each nintendo platform x week day of the given launch date, here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("ign.csv")
datetime_df = pd.DataFrame({'year': df["release_year"],
                   'month': df["release_month"],
                   'day': df["release_day"]})
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(datetime_df)

df["week_day"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x : x.weekday_name)

nintendo = ['Wii','Nintendo DS','Nintendo 3DS','Nintendo DS',
            'Game Boy', 'Game Boy Color','Nintendo 64DD','Game Boy Advance',
            'New Nintendo 3DS','GameCube','Nintendo DSi','Super NES']

base_nintendo = df[df["platform"].isin(nintendo)]

data = base_nintendo.groupby(["platform","week_day"]).size()

data =data.unstack().fillna(0).stack()

data
```

with the output:

```
platform          week_day 
Game Boy          Friday         5.0
                  Monday         5.0
                  Saturday       0.0
                  Sunday         0.0
                  Thursday       0.0
                  Tuesday        4.0
                  Wednesday      8.0
Game Boy Advance  Friday       131.0
                  Monday       109.0
                  Saturday       0.0
                  Sunday         1.0
                  Thursday     153.0
                  Tuesday      123.0
                  Wednesday    106.0
Game Boy Color    Friday        89.0
                  Monday        43.0
                  Saturday       1.0
                  Sunday         1.0
                  Thursday      55.0
                  Tuesday       78.0
                  Wednesday     89.0
GameCube          Friday        99.0
                  Monday       100.0
                  Saturday       3.0
                  Sunday         0.0
                  Thursday      83.0
                  Tuesday      124.0
                  Wednesday    100.0
```

I've tried doing:

```
data.groupby("platform").plot("barh")
```

but it only gives me the last platform (wii):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use `seaborn` and plot `barh` .

```
data = data.unstack().fillna(0).stack()
data = data.reset_index().rename(columns={0:'value'})

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
sns.barplot(y='platform',x='value', hue='week_day', data=data, orient='h')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks man, I would like to make a unique barplot for each platform, but thanks in advance !

Comment: just got it worked using sns.catplot() 
sns.catplot(y='week_day',x='value',col="platform",col_wrap=4 ,hue='week_day', data=data,kind= "bar")

Answer (score 1):

Notice that above the plot you get one line for each of your groups such as `Super NES ....`? Those are the `matplotlib.AxesSubplot` object to your other plots.

[`groupby.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.plot.html) actually returns a `matplotlib.AxesSubplot` object for each of your groups.  On the other hand, ipython notebook is only showing your last plot.

The solution is thus: change your `data.groupby("platform").plot("barh")` to `my_axes =  data.groupby("platform").plot("barh")` and then work on them one by one such as

```
for ax in my_axes:
    ax.savefig(filename)
```

Alternative you can do this:

```
gp = data.groupby("platform")
f, axes = plt.subplots(5, 5)  # or any other large enough subplot grid
for k, ax in zip(gp.groups, axes.ravel()):
    gp.get_group(k).plot('barh', ax=ax)
```

Comment: It worked, but it's to poluted, it gives me in the Y axis, the name of the weekday and the platform.